# How do I get a column for Difference, and for % of Budget

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I know this has to be so simple, but I just can't get my head around it.  How would I add two columns to this pivot table with Difference and % of Budget?  (Well, I guess 3 columns, with the 3rd being "Total of Act+Enc"?

I'm thinking Calculated Field, but can you do an IF statement or have it filter by type?  I tried to Group the Actual and Encumbered columns, but didn't know where to go after that.

[image: Data]

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate a difference? Or how to calculate a percentage? Probably not on topic here.

Comment: Check [Show different calculations in PivotTable value fields](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-different-calculations-in-pivottable-value-fields-014d2777-baaf-480b-a32b-98431f48bfec)

Comment: Solved.  I was able to do what I need using Calculated Item.

Comment: Well, this isn't good.  I think because of a combination of having over 25k rows and some columns are actually formula (my real dataset, not the simple sample above), I get an error about having too much data (sorry don't have the error in front of me as its on my work computer).  So I'm thinking of is there anyway to do a calculated field that's something like SUMIF when type is Actual or Encumbered?